# Why stored procedure result is zero?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql, stored-procedures

Work on C# vs 2008. I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005. Using Linq-to-SQL I execute the stored procedure, but the result is zero. When i run the query in Sql server it's work fine

```
 exec spGetInvoiceByDate '03/01/2011 00:00:00 AM','03/31/2011 11:59:59 PM'
```

above syntax works fine.

Here is my SQL Server **stored procedure**

```
create procedure [spGetInvoiceByDate]  
  @Beginning_Date DateTime, @Ending_Date DateTime  
as  
begin  

SELECT * INTO #temp1 FROM (  
SELECT     convert(varchar, ManifestPort.StartDate, 1)+'-'+CASE dbo.ManifestPort.EndDate WHEN '1800-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN 'N/A' ELSE convert(varchar, ManifestPort.EndDate, 1) END AS [Date], Manifest.VesselName, Manifest.VoyageNo, DischargePort.PortName
, ManifestPort.Terminal, COUNT(Seal.ContainerNo) TotalContainers, 0 AS TotalHours, 0 AS TotalFee  
FROM ManifestPort 
INNER JOIN Manifest ON ManifestPort.ManifestNo = Manifest.ManifestNo 
INNER JOIN DischargePort ON ManifestPort.PortCode = DischargePort.PortCode 
INNER JOIN Seal ON ManifestPort.ManifestPortNo = Seal.ManifestPortNo  
WHERE (StartDate BETWEEN @Beginning_Date AND @Ending_Date)                
GROUP BY StartDate,EndDate, VesselName, VoyageNo, PortName, Terminal) AS a  

SELECT * INTO #temp2 FROM (  
SELECT convert(varchar, ManifestPort.StartDate, 1)+'-'+CASE dbo.ManifestPort.EndDate WHEN '1800-01-01 00:00:00.000' THEN 'N/A' ELSE convert(varchar, ManifestPort.EndDate, 1) END AS [Date], Manifest.VesselName, Manifest.VoyageNo, DischargePort.PortName, 
ManifestPort.Terminal, COUNT(Seal.ContainerNo) STotalContainers, 0 AS STotalHours, 0 AS STotalFee  
FROM ManifestPort 
INNER JOIN Manifest ON ManifestPort.ManifestNo = Manifest.ManifestNo 
INNER JOIN DischargePort ON ManifestPort.PortCode = DischargePort.PortCode 
INNER JOIN Seal ON ManifestPort.ManifestPortNo = Seal.ManifestPortNo  
WHERE (StartDate BETWEEN @Beginning_Date AND @Ending_Date ) AND Line = 'CSAV'  
GROUP BY StartDate,EndDate, VesselName, VoyageNo, PortName, Terminal     ) AS b  

SELECT  #temp1.Date,  
        #temp1.VesselName ,  
        #temp1.VoyageNo ,  
        #temp1.PortName ,  
        #temp1.Terminal ,  
        #temp1.TotalContainers ,  
        #temp1.TotalHours ,  
        #temp1.TotalFee, #temp2.STotalContainers, #temp2.STotalHours, #temp2.STotalFee FROM #temp1 INNER JOIN #temp2  
        ON #temp1.Date = #temp2.Date AND #temp1.PortName = #temp2.PortName AND #temp1.Terminal = #temp2.Terminal AND #temp1.VesselName = #temp2.VesselName  
        AND #temp1.VoyageNo = #temp2.VoyageNo  

        Order BY #temp1.VesselName, #temp1.VoyageNo  

DROP TABLE #temp1  
DROP TABLE #temp2  

end
```

I use this **C# Linq syntax** to execute the stored procedure:

```
DateTime firstDayOfMonth = Convert.ToDateTime("03/01/2011");
DateTime lastDayOfMonth = Convert.ToDateTime("03/31/2011");

var results = ProviderName.spGetInvoiceByDate(firstDayOfMonth,lastDayOfMonth);
```

Why do I always get result is zero?

Can anybody tell me how to reduce the problem?

Thanks in advance, if you have any question, please ask.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the result is zero'? What's the return type of the `spGetInvoiceByDate` method?

Comment: Well, you need to debug the problem - step by step. Given those input parameters - does the stored procedure itself (in SQL Server Mgmt Studio) return something?? Then: try to run the internal SELECT statements one by one - do they actually produce results?? If not: investigate, why not. Seems like a fairly simple and straightforward debugging session - but without having your database and your tables, trying to **guess** what's wrong from afar is next to impossible

Comment: As far as I can tell, the proc was meant to return a resultset not a scalar nor is the Return value of the proc ever set. So, I doubt anyone has any idea why you expected to get some non-zero value for the return value.

Comment: Your SQL code includes the whole 31st of march, the C# code only includes midnight (0:00).

Comment: You don't need to drop the temp tables at the end of the stored proc - temp tables are automatically dropped at the end of the procedure that creates them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried executing the stored proc (on SQL Server Management Studio) by replacing @Beginning_Date and @Ending_Date with the values you pass in to your C# Linq code? 
Does it return any result?
If it's also 0, that explains why your Linq code returns 0.

Hope that helps.

Comment: stored procedure works fine on sql server.exec spGetInvoiceByDate '03/01/2011 00:00:00 AM','03/31/2011 11:59:59 PM' output is ok.but run on linq give result=0

Comment: **output is ok** ?, does it return a result set ? what is the output you see in sql server

Comment: what u mean by out put in sql server.When a query run on sql ,than out put show in grid

Comment: Yah! it's return a result set ,when run on sql server.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above by Hans Kesting, you're not using the same date/times in your call to the stored procedure in your SQL query vs. your call via the code.

```
exec spGetInvoiceByDate '03/01/2011 00:00:00 AM','03/31/2011 11:59:59 PM'
```

Set the end date in the code to March 31 2011, 11:59:59 PM.

```
DateTime firstDayOfMonth = Convert.ToDateTime("03/01/2011");
DateTime lastDayOfMonth = Convert.ToDateTime("03/31/2011 11:59:59 PM");

var results = ProviderName.spGetInvoiceByDate(firstDayOfMonth,lastDayOfMonth);
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq to SQL does not support code generation for stored procedures that produce results based on temporary tables. See the LINQ to SQL Limitations on Stored Procedures section in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx for more details. One way to get round this is to temporarily change your stored procedure to use normal tables instead of temporary tables, generate the Linq to Sql code in Visual Studio and then change your stored procedure back to use temporary tables. Delete any unwanted tables created in the temporary version of the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

There's something you're leaving out in the code here...

Normally a result of a single integer implies that you're getting the return code of the procedure, which is used to indicate an error state if one occurred (0 means all was well) and you're not getting the resultset.

Can you post the code (even if it is just reflected) of the `ProviderName.spGetInvoiceByDate(` method? I'm willing to bet that it does something internally that we're not aware of.

Comment: the code of that particular procedure. Right click it and choose "view implementation"

Comment: when i execute the stored procedure using the query give me result set,but when run on Linq show output is zero. exec spGetInvoiceByDate '03/01/2011 00:00:00 AM','03/31/2011 11:59:59 PM'

Comment: In Visual Studio, where you have the line that contains the method `ProviderName.spGetInvoiceByDate` right click `spGetInvoiceByDate` and choose View Implementation and then copy and paste that method in your original question body.

Comment: on debug mode ,right click on spGetInvoiceByDate i don't get any View Implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is due to mismatch in the Date Format. Please verify that the date format of parameters are same in `C#` as well as `SQL Server`. In case of mismatch you can convert the format in Stored Procedure itself.